# setOnCompletionListener method isn't getting invoked in my Media Player

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a music player app using kotlin. I defined a **mediaPlayer** object in my **MainActivity** and is using it in **SongPlayingFragments**.
The problem I am having is that the next Songs are automatically playing.
I tried to figure out the problem and found that my **onCompletionListener** isn't working or rather say, is not getting invoked.
I fail to troubleshoot the problem myself and therefore is searching for any solutions or any other way to change my songs automatically.

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    CurrentSongHelper.isPlaying=true
    CurrentSongHelper.isShuffle= false
    CurrentSongHelper.isLoop = false
    var path: String ?= null
    var _songArtist: String ?= null
    var _songTitle: String ?= null
    var songId: Long = 0
    try {
        path = arguments?.getString("path")
        _songArtist = arguments?.getString("SongArtist")
        _songTitle = arguments?.getString("SongTitle")
        songId = arguments?.getInt("SongId")!!.toLong()
        currentPosition = arguments!!.getInt("SongPosition")
        fetchSongs = arguments?.getParcelableArrayList("SongData")

        CurrentSongHelper.songPath=path
        CurrentSongHelper.songArtist= _songArtist
        CurrentSongHelper.songTitle= _songTitle
        CurrentSongHelper.songId= songId
        CurrentSongHelper.currentPosition= currentPosition

        updateTextViews(CurrentSongHelper?.songTitle as String, CurrentSongHelper?.songArtist as String)
    }catch (e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    //processInformation(mediaPlayer as MediaPlayer)
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(myActivity as Context, Uri.parse(path))
        mediaPlayer.prepare()
        mediaPlayer.start()
    }catch (e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    processInformation(mediaPlayer)
    if(CurrentSongHelper.isPlaying ){
        playPauseImageButton?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_icon)
    }else{
        playPauseImageButton?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_icon )
    }

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Changing Song", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        onSongComplete()
    }
    clickHandler()
    audioVisualization?.linkTo(mediaPlayer)
}
```

onSongComplete() Function is supposed to change my songs.
The Toast "Changing song" isn't shwing up and therefore i assume that whatever the problem is, it's causing my Listener not to get invoked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest not to catch generic exceptions, you never really know in what state you are. Only catch specific exceptions when needed and properly handle them. It will make debugging easier.

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Changing Song", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        onSongComplete()
    }
```

with

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Changing Song", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        onSongComplete()
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to invoke `setOnCompletionListener()`, you should disable looping with a call to `mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
     videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash3));
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> {
           //here code will come and it works.
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke completion listener code after mediaplayer.start()

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(myActivity as Context, Uri.parse(path))
    mediaPlayer.prepare()
    mediaPlayer.start()

 mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Changing Song", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    onSongComplete()
}

}catch (e: Exception){
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```